# Конвертация из xml (фид яндекс маркета) в CSV

Tags: php, linux, xml, bash, csv

Какие есть простые варианты конвертирования **yml-файла (xml)** яндекс.маркета в **CSV**?
Нужны все данные артикула в одной строке.

Пример файла:
https://yandex.ru/support/partnermarket/yml/about-yml.xml#pricelist

Comment: там же нелинейные данные (в примере по ссылке). есть и массивы, и вложенные структуры. как вы представляете себе этот винегрет в виде csv? // часть информации (ту, которая «линейная») можно конвертировать с помощью пакета [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) (должен присутствовать в популярных дистрибутивах).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один фрилансер сделал, вот рабочий вариант на php:

```
  <?php
  ignore_user_abort(1);
   error_reporting(0);
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$cat = array();
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('./in.xml');
while($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'category');
    while($xml->name === 'category'){
        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
        $id = +$xml->getAttribute("id");
        $name = ''. $node;
        $cat[$id] = $name;  
    $xml->next('category');
    }
$xml->close();          
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('./in.xml'); 
$allparams = array();
$idparams = array();
while($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'offer');
    while($xml->name === 'offer'){
        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML()); 
        $id = +$xml->getAttribute("id");

        foreach ($node->param as $param){
            $name = ''. $param['name'];
            $value = ''. $param;
            $allparams[] = ''. $param['name'];              
            $idparams[$id][$name] = $value;
        }               
    $xml->next('offer');
    }
$xml->close();
$allparams = array_unique($allparams);
sort($allparams);
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('./in.xml');
$flag = true;   
while($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'offer');
    while($xml->name === 'offer'){
        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());

        $id = $xml->getAttribute("id");
        $available = $xml->getAttribute("available");
        $url = $node->url;
        $price = $node->price;
        $currencyId = $node->currencyId;
        $delivery = $node->delivery;
        $local_delivery_cost = $node->local_delivery_cost;
        $typePrefix = $node->typePrefix;
        $vendor = $node->vendor;
        $vendorCode = $node->vendorCode;
        $model = $node->model;
        $description = $node->description;
        $cpa = $node->cpa;
        $weight = $node->weight;
        $pickup = $node->pickup;
        $c = +$node->categoryId;
        $category = $cat[$c];
        $picture = '';
        foreach ($node->picture as $pic){
            $picture .= $pic .' ';             
        }                   
        if($flag){
            $str = '"id";"Наличие";"url товара";"Цена";"Валюта";"Доставка";"Цена доставки";"Тип";"Производитель";"Код производителя";"Модель";"Описание";"Заказ на маркете";"Вес";"url картинки";"Самовывоз";"Категория";';
            $j = count($allparams);
            while($j-- > 0){
                $str .= '"'. $allparams[$j] .'";';
            }
            $str .= PHP_EOL;
            $str = mb_convert_encoding ($str ,"Windows-1251" , "UTF-8" );           
            $path = fopen("out.csv", "a+");
            fwrite($path, $str);
            fclose($path);
            $flag = false;
        }
        $params = '';
        $j = count($allparams);
        while($j-- > 0){                
            $params .= '"'. $idparams[$id][$allparams[$j]] .'";';           
        }           
        $str = '"'. $id .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $available .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $url .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $price .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $currencyId .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $delivery .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $local_delivery_cost .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $typePrefix .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $vendor .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $vendorCode .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $model .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $description .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $cpa .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $weight .'";';         
        $str .= '"'. $picture .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $pickup .'";';
        $str .= '"'. $category .'";';
        $str .= $params;
        $str .= PHP_EOL;

        $str = mb_convert_encoding ($str ,"Windows-1251" , "UTF-8" );           
        $path = fopen("out.csv", "a+");
        fwrite($path, $str);
        fclose($path);              
    $xml->next('offer');
    }
$xml->close();
gc_enable();
  echo 'ok';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

если интересуют только линейные данные (без массивов и вложенных структур), то можно воспользоваться программами из пакета [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/), который, скорее всего, входит в репозитории всех популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

если скопировать и сохранить в файле `primer` то, что приведено по вашей ссылке, то вот так можно извлекать (линейные) данные, представляя их в формате *csv*:

```
$ cat primer | sed '1s/windows-1251/utf-8/' | xml2 | \
  grep /yml_catalog/shop/offers/offer | \
  2csv /yml_catalog/shop/offers/offer @id name price
158,Смартфон Apple iPhone 6s 128gb Space Gray,55690
159,Наушники Koss Sporta Pro,3045.5
```

Comment: пожалуйста, расшифруйте вызов этой команды. Что в каком порядке и как обрабатывается.

Comment: данные обрабатываются в линейном порядке: `программа1 аргументы | программа2 аргументы | программа3 аргументы ...` — всё, что выдала в stdout `программа1`, передаётся на stdin `программы2`, а всё, что выдала в stdout `программа2`, передаётся на stdin `программы3`. и т.д. подробнее: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)